# The topology of $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R^d})$ induced by two different families of seminorms.

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, topological-vector-spaces, schwartz-space

Let $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R^d})$ be the Schwartz class on $\mathbb{R^d}$ and define the following two families of seminorms.$$\rho_{\alpha\beta}(f):= \|x^\alpha\partial^\beta f\|_\infty \\\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(f):=\|x^\alpha\partial^\beta(f)\|_{L^1}$$, where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{Z^d}$ are multi-indices.

I know that $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R^d})$ is a Frechet space when equipped with the first norm.Let's call the topologies induced by them $T_1$ and $T_2$ respectively. Now I am trying to show the $\sigma_{\alpha\beta}$ induces the same norm on $\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R^d})$. Would it suffice to show the existence of two constants $c_{\alpha\beta}$ an $C_{\alpha\beta}$ such that $$c_{\alpha\beta}\rho_{\alpha\beta}(f)\leq\sigma_{\alpha\beta}(f)\leq C_{\alpha\beta}(f)\rho_{\alpha\beta}(f)$$, for every $f\in\mathbb{S}(\mathbb{R^d})$, ?

Also, I am wondering is there a more concise way of proving it without going back the open sets?

Comment: Is there a difference between $\partial_\beta$ and $\partial^\beta$?

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp my bad. fixed it.

Comment: And why is this inequality straight forward? I don't see it.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp I meant to say up to a constant. Now it's edited properly.

Comment: Yes, it would suffice, but I see no chance for it to be true. What would also suffice is to control each $\sigma_{\alpha \beta}$ with a finite number of $\rho_{\alpha' \beta'}$'s, and conversely.

Comment: You have to change the $\alpha$: if $(1+|x|)^{-|\gamma|}$ is integrable then you can estimate the integral over $x^{\alpha}\partial^\beta f$ by a constanct times the sup-norm of $x^{\alpha +\gamma} \partial^\beta f$.